# How can I make a dynamic array of pointers that each point to an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, dynamic, abstract

For what I'm working on, I'm making a class that holds a dynamic array of different sorts of pets. I have an abstract class of Animal, from which I have a few derived classes (Cat, Dog, Rabbit, Horse, etc.). I need to be able to add an instance of those derived classes to the end of the dynamic array. In the list object, I have a double pointer (Pet** pets) which is what is supposed to store the list of objects that have Pet as a base class. My thinking is that since Pet is the base class, then each pet pointer should be able to point to an object of type Cat or type Dog, etc.

I have a function in the PetArray class that is supposed to add an object to the end of the list, but I have a couple of issues:

1. Every time this function is called, all entries in PetArray become the same as the last element I just tried to add.
2. Later when I try to print info about each element in the array, the program crashes. I have a for loop that is supposed to print information about each element in the array, but my program always crashes on the first iteration of the loop when it's trying to access member data.

I am totally stuck here and am not sure how to fix what's wrong. Any help anybody can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're not forbidden from making a `std::vector<Pet*>`, I would recommend using that instead.

Comment: I'd use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pet>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Pet>>`

Comment: Sit down with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and explain to it what each line in your function does. Rubber ducks are pretty dim, that's what happens when your head is full of air, so be patient and explain slowly. If Duckie raises any objections, Reconsider the code.

Comment: For what it's worth: There's nothing I'm seeing in this code that looks like it would cause all entries in the PetArray to be overwritten, I just see the fairly severe memory leak. This is one reason why minimal complete examples are helpful.

Comment: Oh, memory leak because I didn't delete pets before reinitializing it?

Comment: The leak aside, the rest of the code *should* work, but it is not optimal. This is starting to smell of a possible [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation or other memory corruption. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how `PetArray` is actually being used.

Comment: Your `add()`'s job is, presumably, to add one `Pet` to your dynamic array. This should require at most one reallocation, when it becomes necessary to grow the dynamic array to accomodate the new `Pet`. One reallocation, copy the existing array to the new array, add the new value, delete the old array. So, can you explain ***why you have two `new` statements in there***? What is the 2nd one supposed to accomplish? As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical.

Comment: @thp94 There's two `new` allocations and zero `delete[]`s in your `add` method. You don't delete the old `pets` array, and you don't delete `temp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct, but your implementation of `add()` is not optimal.  If nothing else, it is leaking the old `pets` array.  But it is also just coded more complicated than it needs to be.

It should look more like the following instead (assuming `pets` and `length` were initialized properly before `add()` is called, and that `PetArray` is managing them correctly per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and that your `PetArray` object is not being corrupted from another bug elsewhere in your code):

```cpp
void PetArray::add(Pet *p)
{
    Pet** temp = new Pet*[length+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = pets[i];
    }
    temp[length] = p;
    
    delete[] pets;
    pets = temp;
    ++length;
}
```

**UPDATE**: you are not `add()`'ing objects to your array correctly. You are creating your derived objects in *automatic* memory, not in *dynamic* memory. You are taking pointers to the objects right before they go out of scope and get destroyed, and then you add the now-invalid pointers to your array.

```
Pet* p;
...
if(species == "Cat"){
    ...
    Cat c(name, species, age, weight, length);
    p = &c;
} // <-- c is destroyed here!
// same goes for the other animal types, too...
...
add(p); // <-- p is invalid here!
```

This explains both problems you described. You are adding pointers to local memory that gets reused in each loop iteration, and then you crash when trying to access invalid objects.

You need to `new` the objects instead, eg:

```
Pet* p;
...
if(species == "Cat"){
    ...
    p = new Cat(name, species, age, weight, length);
}
// same for the other animal types, too...
...
add(p);
```